# If I don't synchronize this method I'll get wrong values?

Tags: java, asynchronous, crc

```
public static int getCRC16(byte[] bytes) {
    CRC16 crc = new CRC16();
    crc.reset();
    crc.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    return (int) crc.getValue();
}
```

Tons of threads will hit this method, if I don't synchronize I'll get a wrong `crc` for a specific thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `static` method. Usually you need to worry about `thread safety` when you're dealing with the `state` of an object. For example, if you were changing values inside the `CRC16` class itself, but you're not. Your function just takes an input `bytes` and returns an output `crc.getValue()`.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is fine, as long as you don't use any shared variables. The `bytes`and `crc`are local per thread. That's why they are called local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the other answers, threads do *not* extend the Java language regarding visibility and scopes, only regarding the mode of execution of code, which means that values that only a single object can access or which are only valid locally are not needed to synchronize - only if values are being shared between multiple objects (static fields of a class, or a singleton instance where all accessors are getting returned the same object) synchronization gets worthy philosophizing about.